USB stopped working after upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04 LTS
Searching through various websites I did not find an answer to my problem, so I decided to start my own thread.
The problem is as follows, on my computer I was using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, everything worked perfectly. I decided to upgrade my computer to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS because I received a message about an available upgrade.
The upgrade was successful with one small exception. My USB-connected mouse and keyboard to the computer's rear ports stopped working. Only when I switched them to the front ports of the computer did they start working normally.
I don't want to use my computer's front ports because I have other things here on a daily basis. For a test, I tried firing up Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from USB as a live version, but the same error occurred. Immediately when Ubuntu 24.04 LTS starts up then my devices connected to the back ports of the computer stop working. This is an error related only to this version, as I mentioned, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS everything works perfectly, the same on, for example, Windows 11.
EDIT:
I don't see any information on what type these ports are. If there is any way to find out, I'd be happy to find out and catch up.
The only thing I know is that I have two USB ports on the front which are blue. On the back I have two blue and two black USB ports. I only use these blue USB ports on a daily basis, on the back as well as the front.
The situation is so strange that when I plugged my keyboard and mouse into the black ports in the back, the mouse and keyboard work perfectly, while in the blue USB ports that are in the back they do not work. Why is the situation strange? Headphones plugged on USB into the front blue ports work perfectly on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and so do the keyboard and mouse if I plug them into the blue ports on the front.
It appears that when I use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS then both blue USB ports that are on the back of the computer stop working, and only the black ones that are on the back and the blue ones that are on the front work. Out of curiosity, I also tried Fedora Workstation 40 and Kubuntu 24.04 LTS, where the situation is identical to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. On the predecessor 22.04.4 LTS, all USB ports work flawlessly.
After discovering that the black ports work it doesn't bother me as much, but I would still like to know why it is happening. When I swap USB cables from one port to another I don't have to do a reboot, it's immediately apparent if the mouse and keyboard work on the new port or not. Below are the hardware specifications of my computer:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti / Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
Motherboard: Gigabyte H81M-D2V
RAM: 8 GB
Keyboard: CHERRY KC 1000
Mouse: Logic LM-STARR-ONE

More information is needed here.  What type of USB port did you connect to on the back?  What type of USB port did you connect to on the front?  Some ports are strickly USB2 while others are USB3 capable. What is your hardware?  I've found mice can be connected and disconnected without reboot.  As you swap that mouse from front to back, does it not work (and of course, does it again work when reconnected on a front port?)

@quill I have added more information and hardware specifications to the main thread

I knew about "super speed" ports, noted with SS next to them but not color.  A quick search shows the color has meaning.  Later red, even faster ports were introduced.  If that wasn't enough now there are USB-C ports which have a slightly different connector.  Try an internet search of "blue usb ports vs black usb ports" to see more about it.

0
It happened to me too. The ports actually do work, but in a very weird way. I got an USB-TTL converter, based on CP2102 chip. It works in two other computers I got, but with my ASUS TUF - it is recognised only with one of four cables I used previously, in just one port of three and randomly fails in the middle of transmission.
