Mounting USB GPT FAT on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I was reading post to install my USB on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
With $ sudo fdisk -l I got:
Disk /dev/sdb: 241.87 GiB, 259710255104 bytes, 507246592 sectors
Disk model: SD Card Reader  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5F610759-0934-4674-96A8-0F49DB6C7B1A

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  411648 507244543 506832896 241.7G Microsoft basic data

I was reading this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/85459/733009
Unfortunately sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils I got:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate

Then I only Installed: sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse.
And later I was obtain to install from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/exfat-fuse_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb.html
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/exfat-utils/exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb
--2024-06-20 00:45:50--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/exfat-utils/exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.82, 185.125.190.83, 91.189.91.83, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.82|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 40672 (40K) [application/vnd.debian.binary-package]
Saving to: ‘exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb’

exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb     100%[=============================================================>]  39.72K   170KB/s    in 0.2s    

2024-06-20 00:45:51 (170 KB/s) - ‘exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb’ saved [40672/40672]

But, I can't to install:
sudo dpkg -i exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package exfat-utils.
(Reading database ... 171221 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking exfat-utils (1.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/exfatlabel.8.gz', which is also in package exfatprogs 1.2.2-1build1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 exfat-utils_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb

As you can see:
$ lsblk -e7 -o name,fstype,uuid
NAME                      FSTYPE      UUID
sda                                   
├─sda1                    vfat        9478-086C
├─sda2                    ext4        53b9b58d-fc04-4c36-8157-2d8f27ed045f
└─sda3                    LVM2_member oqYowg-z06J-G0th-3Vbh-igM5-KTum-XaS93g
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        b06af9d9-a3d6-4885-9ff1-0afb496beff1
sdb                                   

How I can to install my EXFAT USB?

I was reading this question: https://itsfoss.com/mount-exfat/

Related problem: https://askubuntu.com/q/1518119/733009

Copy the data off it to another machine like a Windows machine. Format the drive as NTFS and copy the data back on. In future the drive if not damaged will always read in both Ubuntu and Windows. FAT is an EXTREMELY old file system. Not really used for data anymore.

Unfortunately the Card is a JetDrive (https://www.amazon.com/Transcend-JetDrive-Storage-Expansion-TS256GJDL130/dp/B00WGARJIS?ref_=ast_sto_dp&th=1) for MacBook Air (13Inch Early 2015). Precisely I removed the  due to lack of support by Apple.

exFAT support is in the kernel now, you don't need to install anything to mount exFAT partitions. What's the actual problem you're facing?

I am thinking the drive is damaged.
